# Echoing a mulitple line message in alert function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to echo multiple line error in JS alert and I am using below code

**Working code**

```
$str = "This is a error1\\n";
$alert = $str."This is error2"; 


     if(!empty($alert)){
                    ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                                alert('<?php echo $alert;?>');

                        </script>
                    <?php
                }
```

but I need to work on an old written code so this has addslashes function before echo alert like below:

```
$str = "This is a error1\\n";
$alert = $str."This is error2"; 

$alert  = addslashes($alert);
     if(!empty($alert)){
                    ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                                alert('<?php echo $alert;?>');

                        </script>
                    <?php
                }
```

**Output : This is a error1\nThis is error2**

I need this to print in two lines I have also tried with only \n but it is not working then.

Comment: Make it just `\n` and take out addslashes I think

Comment: you're escaping the `\n`, why is that? If you're looking to get a new line break, either remove one of the slashes, or as mentioned above, use `<br>`. Edit: Ok, he removed that comment I was referencing. @GrumpyCrouton 2nd edit: I know that.... ;-) see more comments below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `<br>` doesn't actually work, as it's being printed in a javascript `alert()` which I overlooked initially

Comment: btw, `\n` only shows as a line break in html source/written to a file; what is it that you really want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make javascript do the hard work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var alertArr = ["<?php echo $string1; ?>", "<?php echo $string2; ?>"];
  alert(alertArr.join("\n"));
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0uwmmm3n/
(Magnificent random url by the way)

EDIT: less messy version, maybe more legitimate

```
<?php $alertArr = [$string1, $string2]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var alertArr = <?php echo json_encode($alertArr); ?>;
  alert(alertArr.join("\n"));
</script>
```

RE-EDIT: nah, too much work for a job so simple, two conversions is way too much

Comment: Are there no negative side effects pushing 2 PHP variables to javascript instead of just 1?

Comment: Maybe a little more execution time I guess, but it's really not important here. If I missed something let me know.
EDIT: of course the PHP strings need to NOT contain any `"` character

Comment: I don't think you missed anything, I was legitimately asking :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "This is a error1\\n";
$alert = $str."This is error2";

$alert  = addslashes($alert);
if(!empty($alert)){
   ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">

               alert('<?php echo $alert;?>');

       </script>
   <?php
}
```

I have used this code and it working fine according to your need

if still issue continues then clear your cache

Comment: I just meant to provide soln

Comment: That is understandable, but you didn't. It does not fix the problem, the OP is having. You should either provide an actual solution or just delete your answer.